# How to get full URL [keyword] from google search using http_referer?

Tags: google, http, referrer

I need to get the keyword what user's searched in the google search engine. I tried http_referer in php but got only the origin not the full url and keyword. Kindly share some idea about.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. I've looked into this in the past.

HTTP_Referer is only compatible with http addresses. Https addresses do not pass referer data because they are httpsecure.

Google traffic is coming from https://google.com and therefore it does not pass the HTTP_Referer PHP parameter data.

I wish this wasn't the case.

You can get a pretty accurate view of what keywords users are coming to your site by looking at Webmaster search console.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics?hl=en&siteUrl=